# how to returning distance with function in google maps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-distancematrix-api

i've script from this link [here](http://christianvarga.com/how-to-calculate-driving-distance-between-2-locations-with-google-maps-api/) and i want to make the function returning distance, this's my actually script :

```
var calcRoute = function(origin,destination) {
    var dist;
    var directionsDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var request = {
    origin:origin,
    destination:destination,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      dist = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000;
    }
  });
    return dist;
};
$scope.resto = calcRoute("-7.048357, 110.418877","-7.048443, 110.441022");
```

there are two parameters that I put in function, and i want the function returning the distance but

`return dist;`

in the script not returning the value from

`dist = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000`

i'm using **angularjs** and the **resto** in my View not showing the distance, anyone help me please, there's something wrong with the script or anything else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until the `directionsService.route` function is executed the function `calcRoute` has already executed and returned `dist` which will be undefined.

You will get the value inside the callback function of `directionsService.route`

You can add another parameter (a callback function) to `calcRoute` function. Now once `directionsService.route` gets the response you can pass the value to this new callback function.

Try this.

```
var calcRoute = function(origin,destination,cb) {
    var dist;
    var directionsDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var request = {
    origin:origin,
    destination:destination,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      cb(null, response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000);
    }
    else {
      cb('pass error information');
    }
  });
};
calcRoute("-7.048357, 110.418877","-7.048443, 110.441022", function (err, dist) {
    if (!err) {        
      $scope.resto = dist;
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your fast response @ShankarSangoli.. :)
i'll try your suggestion..i'm really new with this google-maps stuff..thanks